# Welch Transformation to keep the dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, pytorch, signal-processing

I am trying to extract the `scipy.signal.welch` signal from a temporal 1d time series and since I am not adept in signal processing I have no idea why the dimensions shrink when returned.

I need to concatenate the temporal to the spectral as another channel so if the temporal is of shape:

```
[batches, channels, sample_length]
```

then I expect to get after the concatenation:

```
[batches, 2*channels, sample_length]
```

but when I try to train my model an error is thrown because the size of the spectral doesn't match the temporal (the temporal size is 16):

```
size mismatch, m1: [2 x 9], m2: [16 x 16]
```

I tried to look at the documentation but they don't mention why it shrinks it and how it can be avoided.

Comment: `scipy.signal.welch` has a `return_onesided` which you could set to `False` to get the full spectrum. That may be the same size as the temporal if `nperseg` matches the length of the temporal. Providing the portion of the code you use to call `scipy.signal.welch` and how you pass the result to your model would make this question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SleuthEye said, I set the the `return_onesided` to `False` like so:

```
scipy.signal.welch(temporal, axis=-1, return_onesided=False, nperseg=temporal.shape[0])
```